# Bind Asp hyperlink navigate url dynamically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, .net

I have to bind the navigate url property based on a specific condition . The hyperlink control is based inside the repeater . 
I have created a hyperlink property.code is below

```
HyperLink Hypltitle = (HyperLink)HmPgRptbind.FindControl("Hypltitle");
//some code condition
if(condition satisfies){
 Hypltitle.NavigateUrl = databind;
}
<asp:Repeater ID="HmPgRptbind" runat="server" OnItemCommand="HmPgRptbind_ItemCommand">
 <asp:HyperLink ID="Hypltitle" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>'  Target="_blank"></asp:HyperLink>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The problem is that in quick watch data is getting binded to navigate url property but the  href link is not avaliable in page.
Hope I am being specific to the issue?
Any suggestions on this would be really helpful..Thanks in Advance